# Read FASTQ file into a Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bioinformatics, fastq

I'm trying to read FASTQ files into Spark dataframes. I have some difficulties because FASTQ is a multi line format.

Example:

```
@seq1
AGTCAGTCGAC
+
?@@FFBFFDDH
@seq2
CCAGCGTCTCG
+
?88ADA?BDF8
```

Is there a way to get these data in a Spark dataframe like

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| identifier  | sequence    | quality    |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
|seq1         |AGTCAGTCGAC  |?@@FFBFFDDH |
|seq2         |CCAGCGTCTCG  |?88ADA?BDF8 |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd slide

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

spark.createDataset(sc.textFile(path).sliding(4, 4).map {
  case Array(id, seq, _, qual) => (id, seq, qual)
}).toDF("identifier", "sequence", "quality")


// +----------+-----------+-----------+
// |identifier|   sequence|    quality|
// +----------+-----------+-----------+
// |     @seq1|AGTCAGTCGAC|?@@FFBFFDDH|
// |     @seq2|CCAGCGTCTCG|?88ADA?BDF8|
// +----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Note that in theory, fastq format allows to have the sequence and quality wrapped in more than one line. I've never encountered this, though.