# Read Fastq file directly into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bash, bioinformatics, fastq

I'm trying to read a Fastq file directly into a pandas dataframe, similar to the link below:

[Read FASTQ file into a Spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749395/read-fastq-file-into-a-spark-dataframe)

I've searched all over, but just can't find a viable option.

Currently, I'm running the following:

```
cmd = f'zcat {infile} | paste - - - -'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
b = StringIO(p.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8'))

_ = pd.read_csv(b, sep='\t', names=['read_id', 'seq', '+', 'qual'], on_bad_lines='skip', dtype=str, chunksize=1000000)
```

Is there a cleaner way to just use `pandas` instead? I was thinking of setting `sep='\n'`, but then I just get 1 row with multiple columns. Could I maybe read the file in, and then take every 4th row to create the 4 needed columns (or something like that)?

Speed is really what I'm looking for, so the quickest solution would be the best.

*Side note: my Fastq files will not fit in memory, so I will have to chunk the read*

Answer (score 2):

So I found something that works (just in case anyone else wants to do something similar):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(<infile>, sep='\n', header=None).values.reshape(-1, 4), columns=['read_id', 'seq', '+', 'qual'])
```

Got the idea from:

[Transpose the data in a column every nth rows in PANDAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761366/transpose-the-data-in-a-column-every-nth-rows-in-pandas)

*(Thanks @piRSquared for the suggestion)*

Answer (score 0):

I've used this, this works if one have e.g. two files fastq R1/R2, that are gzipped stating their paths in list_of_paths_scanfile:

```
import gzip, glob, os
import pandas as pd

scanfile_name = 'file_name_without_R1|2'

list_of_paths_scanfile = glob.glob('SCANFILES/'+'%s'%scanfile_name+'_R*.fastq.gz')
    
    
for i in range(len(list_of_paths_scanfile)):
        with gzip.open(list_of_paths_scanfile[i],'r') as in_handle:
            df_fq_temp = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(in_handle,sep='\r\n', header=None,engine='python').values.reshape(-1, 4), columns=['read_id', 'seq', '+', 'qual'])
            df_fq.append(df_fq_temp)
```